ReactJS does not change page view , after saving new changes in react file
So when I make some changes in React I save them, and after I hit npm start it does not change the page view.
E.g.: For - I have a button and I am redirected first to google.com but after some time I do change the redirect to github.com, and hit npm start - the page still redirects me to google only and not to GitHub.
I am doing a spring boot project - I have checked all ports conflicts they are ok.
i tried to install node modules again and npm run build command - nothing changed .
i don't know what to do i am new in react , i just don't know what to do other than saving

Are you saying that the hot reload is not working?

@MehrdadMasoumi   it is saying Uncaught Runtime Error - something static js bundle like this somekind of error.  It is Something AXIOS Error

You should use npm run dev instead of npm start!

when i get same error i open web project in new private tab maybe this method fix your problem

i restart my pc 3 times and opened on the chrome and  edge browser still not showing changes .

can u share code ?


it is saying 548 many characters than limit


u should try share via codesandbox or replit
